# What would be the most efficient way to set up classes that belong to a class

Tags: python, class, oop

How would you set up the following class structure, and why?

Class Person represents a Person
Class Room represents a Room

Where I would like to store the Room location of a Person, with the ability to efficiently ask the following two questions:

1) What Room is Person X in? and,
2) Which Persons are in Room Y?

The options I can see are:

- Class Person stores the Room location (question 2 would be inefficient),
- Class Room stores its Persons (question 1 would be inefficient),
- Both of the above (opportunity for data integrity issues) and,
- External dictionary holds the data (seems against the spirit of OOP)

Comment: The "best" way?  What does that mean?  Not to be pedantic but an engineer should always think twice before using the word "best."  The word is meaningless without a value system, which if left implicit renders the answer ambiguous.  You could ask, instead, "Which of the following designs are the most efficient with respect to storage space?"  Or "Which of the following designs would result in the most readable code?"  Or simply, "How would you do it, and why?"

Comment: @JohnWu You're right. In this context I was looking for somewhat subjective answers so I would go with "How would you do it, and why?". Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> External dictionary holds the data (seems against the spirit of OOP)

Or maybe you can implement all approaches at once: you define both associations *Person has a Room* and *Room has many persons*, and also you index everything using a proper data structure to access your objects at the light speed!

That is, you can walk across your object graph using object-oriented associations (i.e. *composition*) and you implement some specific requirements storing your graph in some data structures to fulfill your requirement.

This isn't against the spirit of OOP. It's in favor of good coding practices instead of artificial dogmas.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Matias! When you say define both associations, are you saying defining it at the external structure level, class level, or just conceptually? If I wanted to facilitate a Person to move Rooms say, I imagine I would use aggregation rather than composition? Also, when you mention implementing specific requirements with indexing and proper data structure, are you talking about the external dictionary structure? Is that possible within python or would I have to store the values in a database?

Comment: @Harlekuin Well, AFAIK aggregation is a form of composition! So yes, I would implement that in order to access which room is assigned to a given person without no more hassle and noise than getting the aggregate. In the other hand, when I explain you that you can index your data, I mean that you can use data structures like dictionaries, sets, lists in Python in some part of your program or system to speed up access to your objects under certain conditions.

Comment: @Harlekuin That way you avoid querying an entire collection of objects but those are already stored in a way that you just need to list them.

Comment: @Harlekuin It seems like you could easily store all persons in a dictionary where keys could be `Person.id` and values the persons. And also a dictionary of rooms. So you can get a person or room instantly (`O(1)`) and get their aggregates respectively

Answer (score 2):

Not every problem is a good fit for OOP. This is one of them. :-)

What you basically have here is a two-dimensional grid or matrix.
One axis represents the persons, the other represents the room. The restriction is that a person can only be in one room.

A `list` of (`person`, `room`) tuples seems like a good way to represent this in Python. Here's an example (in IPython), with your two queries:

```
In [1]: locations = [('alfred', 'office'), ('ben', 'storage'), ('charlene', 'office'), ('deborah', 'factory')]

In [2]: [room for person, room in locations if person == 'charlene']
Out[2]: ['office']

In [3]: [person for person, room in locations if room == 'office']
Out[3]: ['alfred', 'charlene']
```

The queries are list comprehensions so they are pretty fast.
Unless your list of locations is *huge*, I don't think performance will be a big problem.

Note that this solution will work well with empty rooms and persons that are not present.

```
In [4]: [room for person, room in locations if person == 'zeke']
Out[4]: []

In [5]: [person for person, room in locations if room == 'maintenance']
Out[5]: []
```

You will have to take care not to insert the same person twice.

Comment: Thanks for replying Roland! I think a list of tuples would still work even in a many-to-many relationship as long as the same combination didn't repeat.  If I had to use the above classes though, I could still use your method using pointers to the Person and Room objects which would take advantage of your succinct queries (i,e, Person.name == 'charlene')

Comment: @Harlekuin I used strings for convenience. You could use arbitrary Python objects.

Comment: Oh right, sorry Roland, I thought when you said "Not every problem is a good fit for OOP" you meant I shouldn't use classes for this problem

Comment: Class hierarchies are a good fit some problems, and a terrible fit for others. Often Python's built-in datastructures will solve the problem just fine. And I like to use `namedtuple` or a `tuple` subclass where possible to make immutable objects so I can't screw them up by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Definately an external structure. That is the spirit of OOP. Classes represent objects. Neither a person is a property of a room, nor a room a property of a person, so there is no reason putting one in another's class. Instead, the dictionary represents a relationship between them, so it should be a new entity.

A simple format would be a dictionary where each key is a room and the value is a list of the people inside it. However, you could probably create a class around it if you need more complex functionality

Comment: IMHO it seems like you're wrong about **neither a person is a property of room** and vice versa. It's not a property, but OP's domain may require persons and rooms to associate both because that's how real-life business works :D

Comment: I agree in the sense that the best structure depends on the operations done on it. Still, in principle, I think the association should not be stored in the entity unless really needed. Associating person with room reduces the reusability of both and probably hurts scalability (what happens when entities and relationships are added?? do we have to modify all existing classes?)relationships are added

Comment: In such *big* project you would define a base class and each domain might add associations to Room and Person specializations. So core Room and Person aren't associated *per se* but it might depend on the domain.

Comment: @blue_note Thanks for the reply - I like the idea of an external dictionary - having the values as Person pointers sounds like the correct answer as per [Wikipedia's article on object composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation)